# In an MVC, is it OK to have Ajax code (in View) request a query rather than Controller

Tags: ajax

I'm working with Tizag tutorials [here](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php) and [here](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php).  I have modified the code a tiny bit, as follows:

order.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
function createRequest() {
    try {
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //alert("Request is XMLHttp");
    } catch (tryMS) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        //alert("Request is ActiveX1");
      } catch (otherMS) {
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          //alert("Request is ActiveX2");
        } catch (failed) {
          request = null;
        }
      }
    }
    return request;
  }
function ajax1(){
    ajaxRequest = createRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            //alert("Request.readyState is 4");
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
    var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
    var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajaxEx1.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>

<form name='myForm'>
Max Age: <input type='text' id='age' /> <br />
Max WPM: <input type='text' id='wpm' />
<br />
Sex: <select id='sex'>
<option>m</option>
<option>f</option>
</select>
<input type='button' onclick='ajax1()' value='Query MySQL' />
</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the page that's called, ajaxEx1.php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpass = "abcd";
$dbname = "test01";
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
$age = $_GET['age'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];
$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($sex);
$wpm = mysql_real_escape_string($wpm);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ajax_example WHERE ae_sex = '$sex'";
if(is_numeric($age))
    $query .= " AND ae_age <= $age";
if(is_numeric($wpm))
    $query .= " AND ae_wpm <= $wpm";
    //Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Name</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Age</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Sex</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>WPM</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_name]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_age]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_sex]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[ae_wpm]</td>";
    $display_string .= "</tr>";
}
echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$display_string .= "</table>";
echo $display_string;
?>
```

This works fine and is pretty straightforward.  However, I note that in this example the query is essentially requested by Javascript in what would be considered a View element in an MVC pattern.  Would that still be good practice in an actual MVC site?  Would the View send some parameters to a file that would either run the query itself or pass it to a DAO and receive the response?

If not, if the above was a piece of an MVC site, how would the Ajax portion would need to be reorganized?

Comment: Recently, I used and modified Opencart, which is based on MVC and I found some ajax scripts in View templates.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this article - http://css.dzone.com/articles/ajax-and-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, you normally post to a controller which construct the model that is passed to the view to display.

You are using AJAX calls to update parts of your view dynamically without reloading the complete view. It is is completely fine to construct your query inside your JavaScript code. If you're concerned about separating model and view code, you may want to look at [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) for client side (JavaScript) MVVM pattern implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me and I was working on a site large enough that it required modularization via the MVC pattern, I would definitely pull out the ajax stuff to a model object and not the view.  Frameworks like Backbone.js work really well for this because the Models have built-in ajax handling and will populate data back and forth for you.

If you wanted to do it yourself you could create a model object that took just the data (not the DOM elements) as arguments and returned the data for you.

```
function AjaxModel() {

    this.get = function(age, wpm, sex, callback) {

        ajaxRequest = createRequest();
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = callback;

        var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajaxEx1.php" + queryString, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    } 
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
var ajaxM = new AjaxModel();
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
ajaxM.get(age, wpm, sex, onComplete);

function onComplete(r) {
    /// your ajax complete method
}
```

If you're site is large enough the inclusion of a Framework like `Backbone.js` is very worth it in my opinion though.

As a side note, the MVC pattern is a model of how to separate logic, but it's not perfect.  Often I find myself creating many views and models, but very few if any controllers.  View logic is very tied to control in javascript so often I find they just aren't needed.  I would do what makes the most sense to you, while making sure that at least your data is separate from everything else.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is OK as long as you know why you're doing it and what the result of it will be ;). But, it's certainly not best practice.

In a MVC application there is usually alot going on "back stage". Every request has it's lifecykle, and the look of this lifecykle depends on the code base it's built upon.

If you choose not to make use of this chain you'll also lose the benefits that comes with it. It may involve various hooks and plugins registered (by you or someone else) to get the system to work as a whole. It may also involve providing system security, such as centralized ACL logic.

I would suggest you use the controller, which in turn requests data from the model. This data can then either be sent directly to the clienten from the controller (as JSON or XML), or to a view that formats the data before it's being handled by the client. But I favour using JSON.

And, the JavaScript should be seperated from the markup (HTML), and put in a .js file.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I would, never ever, make calls into a database directly with an ajax request.

Comment: That makes no sense. Is ajax just supposed to return static html? No. It obviously must touch the database, and nothing that he's done in his example is particularly insecure or leaves the database vulnerable.

Comment: He should have a controller somewhere. And even if his example is not insecure then it is just bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC, the good approach is to use it in the entire app.

So, when doing an ajax request, build the `query string` or `pretty url` acording to your framework needs, implement everything as you would use a normal view (`View <- Controller <- Model`) and just format the view to return the AJAX stuff (partial HTML, JSON, XML, or whatever).

Usually this may be done by just not using a template with the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ok to put you ajax code (make it generic and reusable depending on your needs) in a separate javascript file that you can include in the view that needs that kind of ajax call.

You should implement an ajax controller, that will process you ajax requests and just send the response? if it is data you just return data using json. this is how I am doing it with Zend framework.

Take a quick look at this [Implementing OOP PHP with AJAX, MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454256/implementing-oop-php-with-ajax-mvc)